# Chromecast iOS sender app issue: cannot add -ObjC to -lz for other Linker Flags

Tags: ios, xcode, chromecast, google-cast, sender

I'm trying to build an iOS Chromecast sender app. The instruction says to change the Other Linker Flags to -ObjC.

But my app already uses Other Linker Flags (-lz).

How do I reconcile these two flags to include both?

(adding `-ObjC -lz` or `-lz -ObjC` did not work. I get errors as if -lz is not included)

Comment: What's the error that you get when you include both?

Answer (score 0):

You can have both on the same line. `-lz` is adding zlib, `-ObjC` is telling the compiler to load anything that defines an Objective-C class or category.

In XCode, double click on "*Other Linker Flags*". Assuming its blank (no entryies) click + at the bottom and enter `-ObjC` (note capitalization). Then click + at the bottom and enter `-l"z"`. You should have two lines with the two linker flags.

If you have other linker flags in there, its probably OK to leave them, just make sure those two are there!

Another alternative is to integrate the Cast SDK using [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) - that will automatically setup the linker flags for you!